# Why does the + 1 operator increment by 2 bytes while ++ increments by 1, in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm writing a custom kernel and was trying to write to the video address at 0xb8000. The least significant byte is the ASCII character and the most significant byte is the background/foreground color. Here's my code:

```
#define VIDEO_ADDRESS 0xb8000

void print_char(void) {
    char *vidmem = (char *)VIDEO_ADDRESS;

    // This produces a music note symbol instead of 'A'
    // the music symbol is probably represented by ascii 0x0E
    vidmem[0] = 0x41; //'A'
    vidmem[1] = 0x0E; //yellow on black

    /*
    // This also produces the undesired result above as expected
    // because this is equivalent to the above block of code
    *vidmem = 0x41;
    *(vidmem+1) = 0x0E;
    */

    /*
    // This produces a yellow 'A' on black background as expected.
    *vidmem = 0x41;
    vidmem++;
    *vidmem = 0x0E;
    */

    /*
    // This also produces the correct result (ie, 'A', yellow on black)
    *vidmem = 0x41; 
    vidmem = vidmem + 1;
    *vidmem = 0x0E;
    */
}

void kernel_entry() {
    print_char();
}
```

The assembly kernel entry code:

```
[bits 32]
[extern kernel_entry]
call kernel_entry
jmp $
```

By the time `kernel_entry()` is called I have already set up protected mode so I'm in 32-bit protected mode.

My Makefile is shown below:

```
C_SOURCES = $(wildcard kernel/*.c drivers/*.c)
HEADERS = $(wildcard kernel/*.h drivers/*.h)

OBJ = ${C_SOURCES:.c=.o}

CC = gcc
CCFLAGS = -march=i386
LD = ld
AS = nasm
EMU = qemu-system-i386
#EMUFLAGS = -m 1024 -boot c -enable-kvm -smp 3
EMUFLAGS = -device isa-debug-exit,iobase=0xf4,iosize=0x04 -fda

all: minios

minios: boot/boot.bin kernel.bin
    cat $^ > minios

kernel.bin: kernel/kernel_entry.o ${OBJ}
    $(LD) -o $@ -Ttext 0x1000 $^ --oformat binary

%.o: %.c ${HEADERS}
    $(CC) -ffreestanding -c $< -o $@

%.o: %.asm
    $(AS) $< -f elf64 -o $@

%.bin: %.asm
    $(AS) $< -f bin -I '../../16bit/' -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf *.bin *.dis *.map *.o minios 
    rm -rf kernel/*.o boot/*.bin drivers/*.o

kernel.dis: kernel.bin
    ndisasm -b 64 $< > $@

run: all
    $(EMU) $(EMUFLAGS) minios
```

My question is, why is the `++` not identical to `+1` in this case? The `++` operator is doing the correct thing as it is incrementing by the size of the variable type (ie char) but the `+` operator seems to be incrementing by 2 bytes. Why is that?

Comment: How about `vidmem = vidmem + 1` ?

Comment: By definition of the language, the value of the expression "p++" is the value of p *before* the increment. If you want it be the same as "p+1", use "++p" (or just never use the ++ operator ever, and you'll never be confused by it).

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker, but `vidmem++` happens _before_ `vidmim` is dereferenced, so it's already incremented by then.

Comment: These should all be doing basically the same thing. Are you talking about another bit of code not shown?

Comment: I suspect something other than the code you're showing us is the problem.

Comment: ... which is why we generally ask for a [mcve] to inform debugging questions.

Comment: @EugeneSh. vidmem =  vidmem + 1 also produces the correct result. I've updated my question to reflect this. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can try printing (with `%p`) `&vidmem[1]`, `vidmem+1` and `vidmem` after you've done the `++`.

Comment: If you can get hex dump of that memory, do so and examine results. Also, you should be able to examine the assembly code produced by the C compiler, you should look at that too.

Comment: Please provide an *actual mcve*. Did you run these 2 codes in *isolation*? If you have *2 of them* at the same time it is naturally not going to work. Also, you'd very likely want to use `unsigned char`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I was running a 64-bit kernel image on a 32-bit QEMU emulator. Once I cross-compiled all the assembly and C source using a 32 compiler, I am able to see everything working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

If `vidmem` is really defined as posted, there is no reason for the `(vidmem+1)` to compute use an increment of 2 bytes.  Indeed `(vidmem+1)` and `vidmem++` should have the same effect in terms of byte increment, even id `vidmem` was defined with a different data pointer type, as long as it is not `void`.

Note that the macro is incorrect: you should remove the `;` at the end of `#define VIDEO_ADDRESS 0xb8000;`

Note also that your function is inconsistent too: if you have all 4 variants as posted, the contents of the video memory will not be as commented. If you are just enumerating alternative tests that you tried, post the code for each test separately with the corresponding observation.

Comment: This is essentially all that is relevant. The rest is assembly code and a c function that calls this function. There is no printf. I haven't defined that yet in my kernel.

Comment: Routinely suggesting `printf` may not always work. You need some other hacks. For Linux kernels, `printk`.

Comment: You either have a compiler bug, or something you think isn't relevant is.   That is why people are asking you to post more information, so they can help you:  Isolate the two sequences, compile into assembly and look at the instructions generated.   Your problem should be obvious; if it isn't post the isolated and disassembled versions.

Comment: I made a mistake in typing the code here in SO. I removed the ; after #define. I do not have this in my code. I'm also running each block of code individually. I've modified the posted code to reflect this.